# How do I get the comments and attachment details for Bugzilla using python and XML-RPC?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I am writing a python script using the python-bugzilla 1.1.0 pypi. I am having a hard time trying to get some of the tags (some may not be supported with the package) from a bug on Bugzilla. Here is the code I have so far:

```
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url='https://bugzilla.redhat.com/xmlrpc.cgi')
bug = bz.getbug(495561)

print bug.description         #this works (it's the first comment)
```

I don't know how to get the rest of the comments. Also I don;t know how the get access to an attached file with the bug as well. Can anyone help me with this? Are comments and downloading attached file not supported with this package?

Comment: Try: `print dir(bug)` it will tell you what attributes it has.  `help(bug)` should also be useful.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks for the help, so it seems like it is not possible to do what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can get the comments with:

```
for comment in bug.comments:
   print comment
```

Where comments have links you can download them with urllib2, scapy or some such and where there is an attachment you can get the ID from the comment and then use `bugzilla.openattachment(ID)` to get it.

Comment: I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 132, in <module>
    downloadFile = bugzilla.openattachment(2080);
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openattachment'
`

Comment: Could it be so because I am using Bugzilla 4.2.5?

Comment: I am on a Linux box and bugzilla tells me it is version 1.1.0 - installed with pip install python_bugzilla tonight. Try `bugzilla.Bugzilla42.openattachment`

Comment: The version of the bugzilla-python package is 1.1.0. I am asking about the version of Bugzilla itself